# Kubernetes anti-affinity rule to spread Deployment Pods to at least 2 nodes

Tags: kubernetes, scheduler, scheduling, kubernetes-pod, affinity

I have the following anti-affinity rule configured in my k8s Deployment:

```
spec:
  ...
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      environment: qa
  ...
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
        environment: qa
        version: v0
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - my-app
            topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

In which I say that I do not want any of the Pod replica to be scheduled on a node of my k8s cluster in which is already present a Pod of the same application. So, for instance, having:

```
nodes(a,b,c) = 3
replicas(1,2,3) = 3
```

**replica_1** scheduled in **node_a**, **replica_2** scheduled in **node_b** and **replica_3** scheduled in **node_c**

As such, I have each Pod scheduled in different nodes.

However, I was wondering if there is a way to specify that: "I want to spread my Pods in at least 2 nodes" to guarantee high availability without spreading all the Pods to other nodes, for example:

```
nodes(a,b,c) = 3
replicas(1,2,3) = 3
```

**replica_1** scheduled in **node_a**, **replica_2** scheduled in **node_b** and **replica_3** scheduled (**again**) in **node_a**

So, to sum up, I would like to have a softer constraint, that allow me to guarantee high availability spreading Deployment's replicas across at least 2 nodes, without having to launch a node for each Pod of a certain application.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy it? What did you try to achieve expected result and where is your problem? Did you see this page: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity?

Comment: I am using Kubernetes version 1.19, deploying the resources via Kustomize. Actually I am trying trying to spread my Deployment replicas across at least 2 worker nodes, that’s the expected results. Unfortunately I can only achieve the behavior to spread every Pod on as many nodes, resulting in having too many not needed nodes. The level of availability I want is just to have the Deployment replicas (>=2) distributed on at least 2 nodes.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want to spread your replicas equally between the nodes? For example, if you have 3 replicas, you want to have 2 for node A and one for node B? Or if you have 10 replicas, you want to be distributed 5 to 5?

Comment: Equally is not mandatory: if I have 10 replicas and 2 nodes, the Pods can be distributed 9 to 1 as well, the only strict rule is to have the replicas distributed at least to 2 nodes.

Comment: So please look at my answer, in particular at `key` and `values` part. It these fields you can specify, which pods should be used. In my example 2 nodes are in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution to your problem. Look at this example yaml file:

```
spec:
  topologySpreadConstraints:
  - maxSkew: 1
    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
    labelSelector:
    matchLabels:
      example: app
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - worker-1
            - worker-2
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 50
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - worker-1
```

**Idea of this configuration:**
I'm using nodeAffinity here to indicate on which nodes pod can be placed:

```
- key: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

and

```
values:
- worker-1
- worker-2
```

It is important to set the following line:

```
- maxSkew: 1
```

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-topology-spread-constraints/#spread-constraints-for-pods):

> **maxSkew** describes the degree to which Pods may be unevenly distributed. It must be greater than zero.

Thanks to this, the difference in the number of assigned feeds between nodes will always be maximally equal to 1.

This section:

```
      preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
      - weight: 50
        preference:
          matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - worker-1
```

is optional however, it will allow you to adjust the feed distribution on the free nodes even better. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#node-affinity) you can find a description with differences between: `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` and `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`:

> Thus an example of `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` would be "only run the pod on nodes with Intel CPUs" and an example `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` would be "try to run this set of pods in failure zone XYZ, but if it's not possible, then allow some to run elsewhere".

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, actually not really, because this way I need to know the `kubernetes.io/hostname` values when a create the k8s resource. Indeed, if I want to use spot instances I won't be aware of such values at deployment time, moreover, such keys can dynamically change during time so cannot be static values.